# Unable to locate package while building Docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker, containers, apt-get

During my Docker container build process, I attemptted to install a few packages using apt-get install. However the process failed to complete because the 3 of the 4 packages could not be found.

```
Step 1 : RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y netcat  ca-certificates  build-essential  libssl-dev
 ---> Running in 38d22d97ec4a
Err http://http.debian.net jessie InRelease

Err http://http.debian.net jessie-updates InRelease

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease

Err http://http.debian.net jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'http.debian.net'
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://http.debian.net jessie-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'http.debian.net'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease 

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'http.debian.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'http.debian.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package netcat
E: Unable to locate package build-essential
E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev
Removing intermediate container 38d22d97ec4a
2015/08/10 12:03:07 The command [/bin/sh -c apt-get update  && apt-get install -y netcat  ca-certificates  build-essential  libssl-dev] returned a non-zero code: 100
```

At first, I thought this was an issue with my base image, however I have no issues building the container on another VM. Thoughts?

Comment: You're getting hostname lookup failures.  This suggests a DNS problem.  If you just start ` debian:jessie` container, does hostname lookup work correctly (`docker run -it --rm debian:jessie bash`)?

Comment: are you in a "real" linux node, or in Mac, Windows (which complicates)? Are you behind a company proxy?

Comment: @larsks I don't think this is a DNS issue. I am able to pull down and run the container your suggested:

`$ docker run -it --                                                                                                                               rm debian:jessie bash
Unable to find image 'debian:jessie' locally
Pulling repository debian
9a61b6b1315e: Download complete
902b87aaaec9: Download complete
root@f88502de912a:/# exit`

@user2915097 My host is an Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop

Comment: @larks, I think you were right. I had to edit the interface file of my host. Once, I indicated the eth0 was using dhcp, my container built correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @cmanning how did you edit your interface file?

Comment: @SophieGairo My VM's interface file was missing an explicit dhcp declaration. I added the following line `iface eth0 inet dhcp` to `/etc/network/interfaces`. This [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/) might help you editing an interface file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue revolved around the host's network configuration. The eth0 interface was improperly configured. The following commands helped me determine it was a DNS issue.

```
$ docker run --rm debian:jessie ping -c 5 google.com
ping: unknown host
$ docker run --rm debian:jessie ping -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=38 time=37.147 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=38 time=32.917 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=38 time=31.475 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=38 time=30.692 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=38 time=31.180 ms
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 30.692/32.682/37.147/2.352 ms
```

Comment: And what did you do to fix that?

Comment: @lolesque The configuration for eth0 did explicitly declare how my VM determined its IP address. I had to be sure declare `iface eth0 inet dhcp`. This might not be your exact issue but it could be close. I would double check your network configuration of the host that is running the docker containers.

Comment: @lolesque Here is a good link which explain how to fix this issue: https://robinwinslow.uk/2014/08/27/fix-docker-networking/

Comment: @ThomasChemineau that link is broken, do you have an up-to-date one?

Comment: @Corin, I believe this is an updated [link](https://robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/).

Answer (score 5):

I found this answer in a newer question based on the same problem and it fixed the issue for me.

```
$ docker-machine restart default      # Restart the environment
$ eval $(docker-machine env default)  # Refresh your environment settings
```

Answer provided by [Mark Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5229796/mark-smith).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without docker-machine and just docker engine?