# "Unable to locate package build-essential" while Docker build on Debian Jessie

Tags: docker, debian, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, apt

I'm trying to run a Dockerfile that had worked very well until few days ago:

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential xorg libssl-dev libxrender-dev wget gdebi
RUN wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-jessie-amd64.deb
RUN gdebi --n wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-jessie-amd64.deb
EXPOSE 80
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN ["sh", "-c", "python", "manage.py", "db", "upgrade"]
CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

The problem happens during the `apt-get install`:

```
E: Unable to locate package build-essential
E: Unable to locate package xorg
E: Unable to locate package gdebi
```

I checked the `python:2.7` Dockerfile, they build it with a `buildpack-deps:jessie` image, which is a `debian:jessie` image.

I changed nothing since the day it worked well and this Dockerfile run on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, so it's not some kind of network problem.
<s>I tried locally and I got the same errors, so I guess it comes from some changes made in the docker OS images, from the Debian or the buildpack-deps team.</s>

Here is the `source.list` (from `python:2.7`):

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main
```

Also, I don't know how to find in which repo I can find those packages, they say nothing about that on the Debian doc... (https://packages.debian.org/fr/jessie/build-essential)

### EDIT

After a new full test on local machine, it worked well, So I guess the problem come from Amazon itself...

Comment: Is it a network issue? (http://stackoverflow.com/q/31924360/6309)

Comment: Finally, yes: it's a network problem. I found that it don't work when I activate "load-balancing/auto-scaling" mode on AWS EB.
So the problem is still on Amazon, because it should work even on this mode... I continue this discussion on Amazon forums, I close this thread when I understand why this mode don't work to give you the full response ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems fixed on Amazon side, there is no more apt-get install failling on Amazon for me, even on load-balanced :)